# NodeJS generates too many defunct processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forever

We have a NodeJS application deployed with **forever**. We don't know why, but this solution is generating too many defunct processes. In some cases, we need to restart manually the application because this situation collapses our server. We'are logging now the PID and timestamp to investigate the reasons, but I'm not confident that we're going to get something with this.

Has anyone this problem? What type of things do we need to check in our NodeJS application to remove this issue? I'm completely stuck and I don't know which type of things can generate this defunct processes. Our code is really simple, with JS promises, WS request, React, ...

If anyone needs some code (like `package.json` or whatever file) or more info, please just tell me.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your server start external processes using `child_process`? If not, can you try using an alternative to `forever` (like `pm2`) to see if that solves the issue?

Comment: Hi @robertklep. No, our application is so simple. If some of our dependencies are using `child_process`, I don't know. In any case, I will try to test with `pm2`. Any feedback about it? Is better or worse than `forever`?

Comment: It's _different_ from `forever`, so it's mainly to rule out that the defunct processes are being caused by it.

Comment: Ok! let's try with `pm2`. It looks much _professional_ than `forever`, so let's see. Than @robertklep!